# aria 2 with uget 2.0 is aria2 shutdown error

Tags: uget

aria 2 with uget 2.0 is aria2 shutdown error

I have tried many previous solutions but not worked.

URI - http://localhost:9299/rpc

Launch aria2 on startup ticked
shutdown aria2 on exit ticked

Arguments --enable-rpc=true--rpc-listen-port=9299

Comment: yes ofcourse i have installed aria2 plugin aria2 1.18.1 for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: one more thing can you please increase multisegment from 16 to 32 as most download manager supports this please increase multisegment from 16 to 32 as i am using 3g connection so that i can utilise the full speed

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use localhost in a download manager?

Do you have aria2 installed? The plugin only works if the engine is installed separately because Curl is the default engine.